# Problemas em converter objeto num projeto Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

Esse aqui é meu projeto
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando vou submeter o formulário ele dá esse erro em tela
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se trata de um projeto Spring Boot, eu achei que não precisasse de uma classe converter para o combo de categoria, mas como deu a mensagem de erro eu resolvir criar a classe converter como pode ver abaixo;

```
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

import br.com.armazem.model.Categoria;

public class CategoriaConverter implements Converter<String, Categoria> {

    @Override
    public Categoria convert(String codigo) {
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(codigo)) {
            Categoria categoria = new Categoria();
            categoria.setCodigo(Long.valueOf(codigo));
            return categoria;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Sendo que mesmo assim ele continuar gerando erro, o que será que posso fazer?

Eu sou novo programador Spring Boot.

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi muito bem mais se for converter uma string em long tenta isso,
categoria.setCodigo(Long.parseLong(c));

Comment: desculpe @Aderbal mas sua sugestão não ajuda muito, eu acho que meu problema é mais uma questão de configuração do Spring Boot do que a conversão propriamente dita.

Comment: Estou tentando submeter um combo num formulário num projeto Spring Boot